# How to check the response assertion is passed or failed in Jmeter using beanshell

Tags: jmeter, web-api-testing

I want to save the request and response of the sample into a text file, if response assertion is failed.

Here I can save the request and response it to a text file. But I am struck where,

how to check the whether response assertion is passed or failed for the respective sample.

How to validate the is current "Http Request" sample is passed or failed?

Thanks In advance.

Answer (score 1):

1. Add [Beanshell Listener](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_Listener) as a child of your HTTP Request sampler which has Assertion(s)
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   import org.apache.jmeter.assertions.AssertionResult;

   for (AssertionResult assertionResult : sampleResult.getAssertionResults()) {
       if (assertionResult.isFailure()) {
           //do what you need here     
       }
   }
   ```

As Listeners are executed **after** assertions the listener will have information regarding all assertion results therefore you will be able to conditionally store request/response details into a file.

---

Be aware that starting from [JMeter version 3.0](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/5-key-things-you-need-know-about-jmeter-30) the [Groovy](http://www.groovy-lang.org/) scripting engine is being shipped with JMeter so consider switching to [JSR223 Listener](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Listener) and replacing all your Beanshell Test Elements with the [JSR223 equivalents](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223), performancewise it would be much better.

Comment: How to add this my file writing code in BeanShell listener.

Comment: If you use `sampler` shorthand in the PostProcessor the equivalent you should be using in the Listener is `ctx.getCurrentSampler()`, so if you had `sampler.getArguments()` replace it with `ctx.getCurrentSampler().getArguments()` and so on, see [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) for more details.